# Chart.js on a chrome extension, Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chart.js, manifest.json

I have tried everything under the sun to get Chart.JS or any graphing package to work on my chrome extension. After being totally shut down by referencing the package, I installed chart.js locally with NPM.

Now, the primary issue is when I attempt to run it, it said I needed to install Kurkle color, so I did-- and this is the new error I cannot shake no matter what.

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".  Graph.html line 1**

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything, trying to avoid using Kurkle altogether, I cannot shake the error, and frankly I'm not even sure where to look.

[Kurkle is declared but never read, yet still throws me errors. Graph.js File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkFkS.png)
[Graph.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIctk.png)
[Manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nwih.png)

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557